# write List<T> to File

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out Generics. Let's say I have a Person class, and I want to write a list of persons to a file. How to make the method accept any list and if the list is List of Person, the method will be able to write all its fields to a file.

```java
class PERSON {
    String name;
    String surname;

    public PERSON(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
}

class  Lesson7 {
    public <T> void writeToFile(List<T> list) throws Exception{
        Path path = Path.of("C:\\Users\\Professional\\IdeaProjects\\Lesson\\src\\FileWr");
        String lineFirst = "# Name Surname";
        Files.write(path, lineFirst.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

        List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        int num = 1;
        for (T t: list) {
            String line = String.valueOf(num++) + "." + " " + t.name + " " + t.surname + System.lineSeparator();
        }

        Files.write(Path.of("FileWr"), rows);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PERSON p1 = new PERSON("Christian", "Bale");
        PERSON p2 = new PERSON("Leo", "Dicaprio");
        List<PERSON> list1 = List.of(p1, p2);
        Lesson7 l7 = new Lesson7();
        l7.writeToFile(list1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens in the case, when T isn't a Person? However I think this is not how you want to use generics in general. As the name implies, generics work with any kind of object you use it with. So I suggest you, that you take a look at generic constraints (e.g. the where keyword in this case) and that you add an interface ```Writeable``` e.g. which adds a ```toLine``` method or something. Then you can constraint T to implement this interface and simply call the ```toLine``` method on any object which is passed to ```writeToFile```

Comment: away from the generic topic , since you have the list object , stream the list and collect objects which are instances of Person class

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: *How to make the method accept any list and if the list is List of Person, the method will be able to write all its fields to a file.* To interpret your requirement exactly, you will probably want to type-check it: if `T` is of type `Person` (don't use all caps for class names) then you will *know* what its fields are and can use them in the write. Otherwise, you *don't* know, so you can call `T.toString()` instead and write using that. Were you to want to be writing them the same in all cases, you would have to use reflection

Comment: You could provide your "Person" class with a proper `toString` implementation and then write the string that this creates to a file. The `toString` method is available in all Java objects, so you would not need to handle different classes differently, but the results in the file of course would vary by the implementation of `toString` in the individual classes.

Comment: @cyberbrain I threw the solution here, as you said, do you think it fits?

Comment: Just as a note: according to naming convention for class names, it should be `Person` – `PERSON` would be for constants.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann (already mentioned)

Comment: @g00se sorry, I missed this hidden in your longish comment (which almost qualifies as an answer).

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `writeToFile` method as follows:

```java
public <T> void writeToFile(List<T> list) throws IOException {
    if (list.isEmpty() || !(list.get(0) instanceof PERSON)) {
        return;
    }
    
    Path path = Path.of("C:\\Users\\Professional\\IdeaProjects\\Lesson\\src\\FileWr");
    String lineFirst = "# Name Surname";
    Files.write(path, lineFirst.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

    List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    int num = 1;
    for (T t : list) {
        PERSON person = (PERSON) t;
        String line = String.valueOf(num++) + ". " + person.name + " " + person.surname + System.lineSeparator();
        rows.add(line);
    }

    Files.write(path, rows, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
}
```

This method first checks if the input list is empty or if its elements are not instances of `PERSON`. If either of these conditions is true, the method returns without writing to the file. Otherwise, it writes the fields of each `PERSON` in the list to the file as specified. Note that you need to cast the generic `T` type to `PERSON` to access its fields. The method uses the `StandardOpenOption.APPEND` option to append the lines to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve it using the toString method and reflection. If you don't get hung up on the PERSON class, it turns out you can try to put any other class that has a toString method. probably I can add a check for the existence of the toString method, if it exists, then fill in the List rows

```
public <T> void writeToFile(List<T> list) throws Exception{
    Path path = Path.of("FileWr");
    String lineFirst = "# Name Surname" + System.lineSeparator();
    Files.write(path,lineFirst.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

    Class<? extends T> clazz = (Class<? extends T>) list.get(0).getClass();
    Method method = clazz.getMethod("toString");

    List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    int num = 1;
    for (T t: list) {
        String line = String.valueOf(num++) + method.invoke(t);
        rows.add(line);
    }
    Files.write(path,rows, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to access `.toString` via reflection. It is a method of `java.lang.Object` so all java classes have some implementation of it, you can call it on any object in Java!
I would just add an `instanceof` check to be sure you only call it on instances of your `PERSON` class, but no cast necessary. Or you use generics boundaries, will add an answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OPs own answer I want to add this variant that uses Java generics boundaries to ensure the method is only called on lists with suitable members:

```java
public <T extends PERSON> void writeToFile(Collection<T> collection) throws Exception {
    Path path = Path.of("FileWr");
    String lineFirst = "# Name Surname" + System.lineSeparator();
    Files.writeString(path, lineFirst, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);

    int row = 1;
    for (PERSON person : collection) {
        String line = String.valueOf(row) + person.toString() + System.lineSeparator();
        Files.writeString(path, line, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        row++;
    }
}
```

I modified a few places of the original method:

- used the generic boundary `T extends PERSON` to ensure all list members are assignable to a `PERSON` variable
- used a `Collection` instead of a `List` for the input parameter as this method does not need to know the type of collection, no specific methods of the `List` interface are used
- used `Files.writeString` for the heading to ensure proper encoding
- used the `StandardOpenOption.CREATE` for writing the header to ensure the file is not appended over and over again with the header and values, but looks "fresh" after every run
- made use of the boundary to handle the values of the collection inside the loop as real `PERSON` instances. This would allow to use any special method of `PERSON` instead of `toString` if this is required.
- used immediate `Files.writeString` inside the loop instead of creating an in-memory list of lines to prevent `OutOfMemoryError`s and get the code more compact. This is not optimized for speed as the multiple operations to open and close the file will stress the OS but optimization is secondary here.
- incremented the row counter in a separate instruction to increase readability. If it were for optimization I would initialize it with 0 and use inline `++row` instead.

Comment: If you don't want to use generics boundaries, you can still go with `public <T> void ...` but have to use this for loop then: `for (T person: collection)`. The call of the `toString` method does _not_ change!